# Android Project

Tags: android, cordova, apk

Guys I've used Cordova to convert a HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT program into an Android project but in the end I get just android-debug.apk without  android-debug-unaligned.apk file.Before I make the keystore and the release version, is there any problem that I miss that file?  Can I upload it by making the release version only with this file?

Comment: The debug version has a debug key only ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the AndroidManifest. Open /myApp/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml and update. VersionCode is what will display in the store; versionName is for your internal use and won't be shown: android:versionCode="10000″ android:versionName="1.0.0″ (Note on format: "10000" = 1.00.00.)

Make sure the following is accurate (change com.developerName.myApp to your own information here and throughout this page):

```
**package="com.developerName.myApp"**
```

Make sure the following is 11 or higher (I choose 19.):

```
**android:minSdkVersion="11"**
```

Open /myApp/config.xml and make sure the widget id and version are the same as in AndroidManifest.xml.

2. The following steps create your private key and the keystore file in which to store it. In Terminal, make sure your starting position is within your app's root folder of /myApp and run the following. (To start commands from your app root folder in Terminal, open the Terminal app, type cd and a space, drag the /myApp folder to Terminal, tap in Terminal to activate its window, then hit Enter.)

   **keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -alias myapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

You'll be prompted to answer several questions. Use only legal characters like letters and numbers, not punctuation. For 2-letter country code, look up this list: http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm

3. You will then review the data presented. At that point, if any of the information is wrong, type the two letters to re-enter that information. For instance, type cn to change your first and last name. Otherwise, confirm the information by typing "yes." Then just hit Enter if the password for the following Terminal information will be the same as the previous.

Your keystore file will be located at /myApp/myapp.keystore. This needs to be copied to a safe place ASAP. Your customers will not be able to update to the next version without this file.

4. Copy myapp.keystore to /platforms/android.

Now it's time to sign the app with the key and create the release version.

5. Open /platforms/android/local.properties (or project.properties) in a text editor.
6. Add these two lines at the end and save, even though it says, "Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!"

   **key.store=myapp.keystore 
   key.alias=myapp**
7. Still in your /myApp folder in Terminal, run:

   **cordova build android --release**

You'll be asked for your password twice and it won't be obfuscated.

8. Your myApp.apk file is put in /myApp/platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-release.apk. (If not there, it may be in /myApp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk.) This is the file you rename and upload to Google Play